# Updating screen fields when background task ends

Tags: swift, multithreading

I am using some APIs to get data.  These are initiated as session.dataTask and I am using classes to encapsulate the API calls, methods and returned properties for each different API.  How should I configure my code so as to update the relevant screen labels and subViews when the API sessions have concluded and the data is available?

The relevant section of the AstronomicalTimes class init is:

```
init (date: Date, lat: Float, long: Float) {
    let coreURL = "https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?"
    let position = "lat=\(lat)&lng=\(long)"
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let dateString = "&date=" + dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    //let dateString = "&date=2020-06-21"
    let urlString = coreURL + position + dateString + "&formatted=0"

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let url = URL(string: urlString)!
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)

    session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

        if let error = error {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                print("Astronomical Times API call failed with error \(nsError.code)")
                return
            }

            if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                print("Astronomical Times API call response is \(response.statusCode)")
            }

            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let astronomicalTimesResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(AstronomicalTimesResponse.self, from: data)
                    print("Astronomical times successfully parsed")
                    self.fillFields(astronomicalTimesResponse.results) //completes all class properties from parsed data
                } catch {
                    print("Error while tide details parsing: \(error)")
                }
            }
    }).resume()
```

A label is assigned the result of the API call in  viewDidLoad() with:

```
currentAstronomicalTimes = AstronomicalTimes(date: savedDate, lat: currentSelection.station.lat, long: currentSelection.station.long)
    lblAstDawn.text = currentAstronomicalTimes.strings.astronomicalTwilightBegin
```

Clearly this doesn't work as the screen is rendered with the labels and subViews blank before the API returns the data.  I can't figure out how to signal the ViewController when the API has completed and then how to redraw the labels etc.  I have tried updating the viewController fields in the API call closure expression but I can't update the UILabels from another class (and I think this approach is messy as the label update logic should really be in the ViewController)

Any help appreciated.

UPDATE after Rob's comments:

I have changed my class definition as advised and it successfully loads the data from the API.  The class definition is as below, note I add a function which takes the loaded data and turns it into time strings and date() for ease of use in viewController (these all appear to be correctly populated after the API call)

```
import Foundation
```

enum AstronomicalTimesError: Error {
    case invalidResponse(Data?, URLResponse?)
}

class AstronomicalTimes {

```
//structures for decoding daylight times
 struct AstronomicalTimesResponse: Decodable {
     public var results: AstronomicalTimes
     public var status: String
 }

 struct AstronomicalTimes: Decodable {
    var sunrise = String()
    var sunset = String()
    var solarNoon = String()
    var dayLength = 0
    var civilTwilightBegin = String()
    var civilTwilightEnd = String()
    var nauticalTwilightBegin = String()
    var nauticalTwilightEnd = String()
    var astronomicalTwilightBegin = String()
    var astronomicalTwilightEnd = String()
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case sunrise = "sunrise"
        case sunset = "sunset"
        case solarNoon = "solar_noon"
        case dayLength = "day_length"
        case civilTwilightBegin = "civil_twilight_begin"
        case civilTwilightEnd = "civil_twilight_end"
        case nauticalTwilightBegin = "nautical_twilight_begin"
        case nauticalTwilightEnd = "nautical_twilight_end"
        case astronomicalTwilightBegin = "astronomical_twilight_begin"
        case astronomicalTwilightEnd = "astronomical_twilight_end"
    }
}
//used to hold string values to enter to label, i.e. time strings for labels
var strings = AstronomicalTimes()

//struct and variable used to hold specific date/times for gradient calculation
struct Times {
    var sunrise = Date()
    var sunset = Date()
    var solarNoon = Date()
    var dayLength = 0
    var civilTwilightBegin = Date()
    var civilTwilightEnd = Date()
    var nauticalTwilightBegin = Date()
    var nauticalTwilightEnd = Date()
    var astronomicalTwilightBegin = Date()
    var astronomicalTwilightEnd = Date()
}
var times = Times()

let date: Date
let latitude: Float
let longitude: Float

init (date: Date, latitude: Float, longitude: Float) {
    self.date = date
    self.latitude = latitude
    self.longitude = longitude
}

func start(completion: @escaping (Result<AstronomicalTimesResponse, Error>) -> Void) {
    var components = URLComponents(string: "https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json")!

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") // just in case your end user isn't using Gregorian calendar
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

    components.queryItems = [
        URLQueryItem(name: "lat", value: "\(latitude)"),
        URLQueryItem(name: "lng", value: "\(longitude)"),
        URLQueryItem(name: "date", value: dateFormatter.string(from: date)),
        URLQueryItem(name: "formatted", value: "0")
    ]

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let url = components.url!
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)

    session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
            return
        }

        guard
            let responseData = data,
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            200 ..< 300 ~= httpResponse.statusCode
        else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(.failure(AstronomicalTimesError.invalidResponse(data, response)))
            }
            return
        }

        do {
            print("Astronomical times api completed with status code ", httpResponse.statusCode)
            let astronomicalTimesResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(AstronomicalTimesResponse.self, from: responseData)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(.success(astronomicalTimesResponse))
                self.fillFields(astronomicalTimesResponse.results)
            }
        } catch let jsonError {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(.failure(jsonError))
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}

func fillFields(_ input: AstronomicalTimes) -> Void {
    //formats output fields into Date() or String (HH:mm) format
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" //Your date format

    times.sunrise = dateFormatter.date(from: input.sunrise) ?? Date()
    times.sunset = dateFormatter.date(from: input.sunset) ?? Date()
    times.solarNoon = dateFormatter.date(from: input.solarNoon) ?? Date()
    times.dayLength = input.dayLength
    times.civilTwilightBegin = dateFormatter.date(from: input.civilTwilightBegin) ?? Date()
    times.civilTwilightEnd = dateFormatter.date(from: input.civilTwilightEnd) ?? Date()
    times.nauticalTwilightBegin = dateFormatter.date(from: input.nauticalTwilightBegin) ?? Date()
    times.nauticalTwilightEnd = dateFormatter.date(from: input.nauticalTwilightEnd) ?? Date()
    times.astronomicalTwilightBegin = dateFormatter.date(from: input.astronomicalTwilightBegin) ?? Date()
    times.astronomicalTwilightEnd = dateFormatter.date(from: input.astronomicalTwilightEnd) ?? Date()

    let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
    timeFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

    strings.sunrise = timeFormatter.string(from: times.sunrise)
    strings.sunset = timeFormatter.string(from: times.sunset)
    strings.solarNoon = timeFormatter.string(from: times.solarNoon)
    strings.dayLength = input.dayLength
    strings.civilTwilightBegin = timeFormatter.string(from: times.civilTwilightBegin)
    strings.civilTwilightEnd = timeFormatter.string(from: times.civilTwilightEnd)
    strings.nauticalTwilightBegin = timeFormatter.string(from: times.nauticalTwilightBegin)
    strings.nauticalTwilightEnd = timeFormatter.string(from: times.nauticalTwilightEnd)
    strings.astronomicalTwilightBegin = timeFormatter.string(from: times.astronomicalTwilightBegin)
    strings.astronomicalTwilightEnd = timeFormatter.string(from: times.astronomicalTwilightEnd)
}
```

}

I then call this from a function within viewController:

```
func getAstronomicalTimes(date: Date, latitude: Float, longitude: Float) -> Void {
    let astronomicalTimes = AstronomicalTimes(date: date, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

    astronomicalTimes.start { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let astronomicalTimesResponse):
            print("astronomical times response ", astronomicalTimesResponse)
            print("label", astronomicalTimes.strings.astronomicalTwilightBegin)
            self.lblAstDawn.text = astronomicalTimes.strings.astronomicalTwilightBegin

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

This function is called within viewDidLoad():

```
getAstronomicalTimes(date: savedDate, latitude: currentSelection.station.lat, longitude: currentSelection.station.long)
```

However, the getAstronomicalTimes(date:latitude:longitude) does not update the lblAstDawn.text as I had hoped for.

Any clues as to where I am getting this wrong?

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.async { self.fillFields(astronomicalTimesResponse.results) }

Comment: Thanks, but that's still not working.  fillFields() populates the class properties.  These properties are accessed in ViewController - I create an instance of the class (which gets the data and then runs fillFields() - in viewDidLoad().  The instance has blanks as initial property values, and these are the values that are returned in viewDidLoad().  The properties are only complete when the API completes so are updated after the labels are assigned  - so the code that populates the screen labels in viewDidLoad() executes before the API returned data is available in the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to supply a completion handler to your `AstronomicalTimes` request, so it can tell your view controller when the data has been retrieved, and the view controller can then update the various fields.

Thus:

```
enum AstronomicalTimesError: Error {
    case invalidResponse(Data?, URLResponse?)
}

class AstronomicalTimes {
    let date: Date
    let latitude: Float // generally we use Double, but for your purposes, this might be adequate
    let longitude: Float

    init (date: Date, latitude: Float, longitude: Float) {
        self.date = date
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
    }

    func start(completion: @escaping (Result<AstronomicalTimesResponse, Error>) -> Void) {
        var components = URLComponents(string: "https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json")!

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") // just in case your end user isn't using Gregorian calendar
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

        components.queryItems = [
            URLQueryItem(name: "lat", value: "\(latitude)"),
            URLQueryItem(name: "lng", value: "\(longitude)"),
            URLQueryItem(name: "date", value: dateFormatter.string(from: date)),
            URLQueryItem(name: "formatted", value: "0")
        ]

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let url = components.url!
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)

        session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
                return
            }

            guard
                let responseData = data,
                let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                200 ..< 300 ~= httpResponse.statusCode
            else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.failure(AstronomicalTimesError.invalidResponse(data, response)))
                }
                return
            }

            do {
                let astronomicalTimesResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(AstronomicalTimesResponse.self, from: responseData)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.success(astronomicalTimesResponse))
                }
            } catch let jsonError {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.failure(jsonError))
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Then your `viewDidLoad` might do something like:

```
override viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let astronomicalTimes = AstronomicalTimes(date: someDate, latitude: someLatitude, longitude: someLongitude)

    astronomicalTimes.start { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let astronomicalTimesResponse):
            // populate your fields here

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rob, thanks for this.  I really appreciate it and it has helped me a lot in making my API call much more elegant.  However, I still can't get the UILabel to update after the api method completes.  The label remains blank.  I have posted an update above with my revised code.  The API method works fine, the class instance has all of the properties correctly returned and formatted, however the labels are still not updated when the API completes.

Comment: `AstronomicalTimes` is calling `fillFields`, but it shouldn’t. The view controller should be doing that. The `AstronomicalTimes` doesn’t have a reference to the view controller that called `start`.

Comment: OK, I have edited out fillFields() and now update the UILabels directly from the instance of the astronomicalTimes instance created in viewDidLoad() and it works!  However, I don't understand why.  All that fillFields() did was to take the raw results from the JSON decode and format them into class properties of AstronomicalTimes.  Why would those properties fail to be passed on to viewController?